# Concerning the use of the possessive form in this context

Tags: possessives

In [this](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/07/02/world/asia/hong-kong-protests-takeaways.html) newspaper article, just under the "China is reluctant to get too involved" heading, the possessive form has been used thus:

> Just a few **minutes’** walk away from the Legislative Council building, the People’s Liberation Army, China’s military, has an outpost with thousands of combat-ready soldiers ready to do Beijing’s bidding.

How can minutes even possess a walk? shouldn't it be "Just a few minutes walk away..." where *few minutes* only qualify the walk instead of possessing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["24 hours' notice" or "24 hours notice"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59575/24-hours-notice-or-24-hours-notice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possessive apostrophe is correct in this case; "A few minutes' walk." See here, for example: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/writing/apostrophe or here: http://random-idea-english.blogspot.com/2014/01/a-ten-minute-walk-ten-minutes-walk.html

Although it sounds odd to think of the walk as belonging to the minutes, it's a way of saying "of" - "A walk of a few minutes."