# At 12 o'clock, I have ... "an hour's break" or "an hour break" or "a one-hour break"?

Tags: time-words

Is this the most natural way to put it:

> I work in a big company. At 12 o'clock I have **an hour break**.

Or should we better say:

> I work in a big company. At 12 o'clock I have **an hour's break**.

Or even

> I work in a big company. At 12 o'clock I have **a one-hour break**.

I would go for the last version, being unsure in how widely the first two are used, under the "[leave well enough alone](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/leave_well_enough_alone)" principle; but still I'm curious.

P.S. My question is different from **[this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34841/apostrophes-in-time-expressions)** because I'd also want to know whether  "**an hour break**" is okay. I was [proofreading this text](http://lang-8.com/1446957/journals/161713941671051623675057263469598607392), chanced upon this expression, decided to inquire whether it was okay, but in the end added some alternative formulations.

I'd like to know which is more widely used and whether there are differences in meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three phrasings are acceptable and mean the same thing. However, it's likely that one particular version - possibly different from the three you mention - is the most common way to say it in your region. That doesn't make it somehow "more correct", but putting it slightly differently than the locals do might give your speech a bit of a foreign sounding flavor.

*An hour break* is what I most commonly hear, probably because it's the shortest to say and I'm generally conversing in an informal register, but you will be understood just fine using any of those three statements.

One very minor thing I will note is that it's *o'clock*, not *o"clock*. The single quote is used to indicate ellipted characters or words in contractions, and *o'clock* is a contraction of *of the clock*.

Answer (score 1):

I think "one-hour break" would be the most common way to say this.

"An hour break" is also acceptable.

People sometimes say "an hour-long break". Though you might argue that that just adds an extra word for no good reason.

It's not "an hour's break" as the break does not belong to the hour: a possessive is not appropriate. If you had a five minute break every hour, you might say "this hour's break", that is, the break for this hour.

Comment: "An hour's break" is perfectly correct usage, because it is *a break **of** one hour*.  This usage isn't as common as it used to be, but you do still see it: [Google Ngrams search result](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+hour%27s+*)

Comment: What @stangdon said. It's already misleading to single out one of OP's alternatives as "better" than any others. It's even worse to mistakenly single out ***an hour's break*** as "wrong" (particularly if, as I more than suspect, that's actually the *most* common form in natural speech).

Comment: @FumbleFingers +1 I'd generally say "I'm going to have an hours break" or "I'm going to have an hour off"

Comment: @Dan: I'd also generally *say* that, but if you're going to *write* it you really should include the apostrophe (Jay is mistaken in supposing the Saxon genitive implies *possession, ownership* in such usages). But when I just checked Google Books for *have an hour / an hour's / a one hour break* the numbers are 626/206/431, so apparently we're in a (slight) minority. On the other hand, switching to the more informal ***get** an hour/.../... break* gives 156/39/8, so in the context of casual speech we at least move up from last position to second place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not my intent to say that a genitive can only mean possession in the sense of "these are MY shoes because I bought and paid for them". As I vaguely recall us discussing elsewhere, "possessive" is a very broad concept: there's a huge difference between "my shoes", "my husband", "my country", "my favorite color", etc. ("Red is MY favorite color! You'll have to pick a different one because I already claimed red.") My intent (mine!) though, was to say that I don't see any sense in which "hour's break" makes sense as a possessive.

Comment: @Jay: What can I say? Your answer text says "a possessive is not appropriate", and you comment that you "don't see any sense" in such usages. But Google Books claims almost 30,000 written instances of, for example, [a week's wages](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+week%27s+wages%22), and even more for [dawn's early light](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dawn%27s+early+light%22). Those usages aren't so much stretching the limits of figurative *possession* as simply reflecting the scope of the genitive form, which is inherently much broader.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "A week's wages" makes sense to me. It is the wages for the week, the wages that belong to that week. "Dawn's early light" means the light that is part of the dawn, the light of the dawn. But "hour's break" isn't the break for the hour or the break produced by the hour or the break associated with the hour. It is the duration of the break. Unless, as I said, you are talking about the break associated with this hour versus the break associated with another hour, like the 9:00 break and the 10:00 break, in which case "this hour's break" would make sense.

Comment: Let me put it this way: Would you say, "I have a one-foot's ruler" or "I have a one-foot ruler"? "We had 40 mile-per-hour's winds" or "We had 40 mile-per-hour winds"? Or generally for words that express the amount or extent of something: "He was a tall's man" or "He was a tall man"? Etc.

Comment: Even though you've switched the word to ***belong***, you're still preoccupied with the notion that the genitive indicates ***possession***. As noted in the relevant Wikipedia article, [In English, strict possession has been found to be expressed in only about 40% of the situations labeled as "possessive" by linguists, a fact which may incline some to prefer the more traditional term "genitive".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possessive#Semantics). I don't claim to be a "linguist", but I'm definitely one of those "some" who prefer the less misleading term.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I didn't switch anything: I used the word "belong" in my original post. :-) I absolutely agree that a possessive or genitive does not necessarily indicate strict "possession". I've said that multiple times. But I'd say that it does indicate some sort of "association" -- happy to hear a better word. Surely your position is not that ANY use of a modifier on a noun calls for a genitive. Just saying "it doesn't have to be ownership in the sense of bought and paid for" doesn't prove that therefore it does mean absolutely anything.