# An hour break vs a break of an hour vs an hour of break

Tags: word-choice

Which sounds more natural? Can they be used interchangeably?

> I have an hour of break.
>
> I have an hour break.
>
> I have a break of an hour.

If I can add another one here.

> He has suffered years of torture.
>
> He has suffered torture for years.

Comment: Related: **[At 12 o'clock, I have … “an hour's break” or “an hour break” or “a one-hour break”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75247/at-12-oclock-i-have-an-hours-break-or-an-hour-break-or-a-one-hour-br)**

Comment: How about a break of an hour? And my other example.

Comment: [I'll take the fifth](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_the_fifth), being a non-native speaker of English.

Answer (score 2):

Your first 3 are all grammatically correct, and can be used more-or-less interchangeably.

The most common one would probably be

> I have an hour break

especially if you move into the past tense. "I had an hour of break" and "I had a break of an hour" just sound more awkward to me than "I had an hour break," though they are still correct.

Another arguably more common way of saying this would

> I took an hour break

As for the suffering ones, they are both correct, and both can be used interchangeably.